# Servlet Path Error

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

For exercise purpose I'm making an application using GWT which consists of a login form. While running it gives an error

> Loading modules com.logvin.LoginForm
>
> [ERROR] Element 'servlet' beginning on line 19 is missing required attribute 'path'
>
> [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML

I am using GWT-RPC and checking if the given username and password is correct or not. I've made few changes in the xml file which are:

```
entry-point class='com.logvin.client.LoginForm'/>   
<servlet> path="/LoginForm" class="com.logvin.gwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl"/>  
  <servlet> 
   <servlet-name>GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-name> 
   <servlet-class>com.logvin.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
 <servlet-name>GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-name> 
 <url-pattern>/LoginForm</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why i'm getting this error again?

Comment: What is this for `entry-point class='com.logvin.client.LoginForm'/>`?

Comment: @RussellGutierrez specifying the application's entry point class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up two XML dialects.

All those `<servlet>` elements should go into your `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, that tells the servlet container (server where you'll deploy your app) how to serve your servlets.

The `*.gwt.xml` file (GWT module) is about telling the GWT compiler (see: compile-time, not runtime) how to compile your code: where to start when loading the app (the `entry-point`), which classes are client-side (will be compiled to JavaScript, others –server-side only– have to be excluded), which GWT modules to import (`inherits`), etc.

Comment: New error is coming **16:31:57.128 [ERROR] [loginform] Unable to find 'loginform.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?** doh!!

Comment: @Vinayak: you have typo in gwt.xml. Check

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you incorrect `gwt.xml`

Your `LoginForm.gwt.xml` should be something like this.

```
<entry-point class="com.logvin.client.LoginForm"/>
<servlet path="/LoginForm"
       class="com.logvin.gwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl" />
```

EDIT:

`servlet` entries are no longer needed in *.gwt.xml files. So you can also delete this line:

```
<servlet path="/LoginForm"
           class="com.logvin.gwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl" />
```

Also, Check you have this entry in your `web.xml`.

Read Example [here](http://www.digizol.com/2008/09/java-gwt-servlets-web-app-tutorial.html)

Comment: Editing in LoginForm.gwt.xml under com.logvin

Comment: Earlier i didnt mentioned **servlet-path** into **LoginForm.gwt.xml**....that time it was giving the same error, so i thought have to give some kind of path to it